# Como fazer filter blur pegar em todo o elemento. Evitar que o blur termine antes do final do background do elemento

Tags: html, css, css3, background

Eu tenho uma `div` que está com `filter:blur()`, porém reparei que o `blur` meio que é para dentro do elemento. O que quero dizer é que ao chegar no limite do box-model a imagem de `background` começa a desaparecer antes da borda, dando impressão que o fundo não ocupa a totalidade do elemento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare na imagem acima, veja que a imagem já está desaparecendo antes mesmo de chegar na borda.

Repare no código que os dois `.box` tem o mesmo tamanho, e veja como o `blur` não completa o conteúdo todo. Existe alguma forma de corrigir esse problema?

```css
div {float:left}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://placecage.com/300/300);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.box2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

A intenção é que o box fique assim, com 100% do conteúdo de background com `blur`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você aplica o blur à div, não vejo como evitar que as bordas fiquem desfocadas. Uma forma é inserir a imagem de fundo em um elemento filho (um `span`, por exemplo) e aplicar `overflow: hidden` na div. Assim a imagem de fundo não irá extrapolar a área da div:

```css
.box {
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: blue;
}

.box span{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 0;
   background-image: url(https://placecage.com/300/300);
   filter: blur(5px);
   transform: scale(1.07);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span></span></div>
```

Comment: Sam acho que o caminho é por ai talvez, mas ainda não ficou legal, veja que colocando uma cor de BG, ainda fica uma contaminação da cor do fundo na borda da imagem http://prntscr.com/mzltxl sera que ainda existe algum ajuste nesse código que pode melhorar esse problema?

Comment: Não entendi :D... se coloccar um background-color, vc diz?

Comment: Não não, na verdade estou falando que o blur ainda está afetando a borda da imagem. Se vc colocar uma cor no body vc vai ver que essa cor fica visível por baixo da imagem, o blur continua "comendo" um pedaço para dentro do background do elemento, repare na segunda imagem da pergunta, veja que o blur pega totalmente

Comment: Aí teria que aumentar um pouco a imagem com transform: scale (editei a resposta)

Comment: Agora sim! Eu tinha tentado com um margin:-5px; e tb tinha dado certo, mas com scale talvez seja até melhor, pq ai a renderização pode ter auxilio da GPU, não lembro se o filter por si só já ativa a GPU... Em todo caso valeu! Amanha eu aceito pq hj já bati no teto haha :D

Comment: Acabei de ler aqui, Ponto de resposta aceita não é tributado!